# Make a sparse matrix with specific probability(Python)

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I want to make a sparse matrix.
The matrix has 0, 1, and -1 as elements, and I want to make the condition that 25% of 1, 25% of -1, and 50% of 0 are in the whole matrix.
I want to express the code implemented in pure-python as SciPy or Tensorflow.

```
for n in range(LWE_N):
    for l in range(LWE_L):
        tmp_S=random.getrandbits(2)
        if tmp_S==1: sk_S[n][l]=1    
        elif tmp_S==0: sk_S[n][l]=-1 
        else: sk_S[n][l]=0
```

Comment: numpy knows that there is no benefit when using a GPU. Is there any way to use the tensorflow API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider renaming your variables LWE_N and LWE_L to lowercase equivalents unless they are global constants.  You can achive a random matrix filled with specified integers with the following:

```
import numpy as np
LWE_N = 10
LWE_L = 5
flat_m = np.random.choice((0, -1, 1,), p=(0.5, 0.25, 0.25), size=LWE_N * LWE_L)
m = flat_m.reshape((LWE_N, LWE_L))
```

See: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html

Comment: thank you for your answer. but, numpy knows that there is no benefit when using a GPU. Is there any way to use the tensorflow API?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create a non-sparse matrix that satisfies the requirement using *numpy*:

```
import numpy as np

n, m = 10, 10
X = np.random.rand(n, m) - 0.5
X = np.sign(X) * (np.abs(X) > 0.25)
```

This can easily be converted into a [sparse](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) one. Yet, When the sparsity is about 0.5, some of the representations may provide little to none advantage over a dense representation.